# Quiero hacer que cuando reproduzca un audio no se pueda reproducir otro hasta que termine el audio actual

Tags: javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quier que no se reproduzca dos audios a la vez, sino que a la hora de seleccionar un audio que no se reproduzca hasta que termine ya que se mezclan los audios y suena raro, alguien me podría guiar?

Comment: Hola, que has intentado?

Comment: He utilizado el setTimeout pero no se m e reproduce el audio y aun no he podido acertar

Comment: Puedes usar una variable para almacenar true/false si un audio se esta reproduciendo. Y agregar el evento `onended` para saber cuándo los audios terminan para resetear ese valor

Comment: No entendi por completo pero gracias, voy a ver como le hago para hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Hola Ryuzeky bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas el código como texto, si creas un booleano **enEjecucion** podrías verificarlo antes de lanzar un nuevo tema.